# Why is std::unique_lock declared here when it isn't used

Tags: c++, condition-variable

I am currently studying Conditional variables and I am starting to get it. However on the code from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/):

```
void print_id (int id) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
  while (!ready) cv.wait(lck);
  // ...
  std::cout << "thread " << id << '\n';
}

void go() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);  <<<<<< ?
  ready = true;
  cv.notify_all();
}
```

In `print_id` I understand the declaration of `lck` since it will be used by `cv.wait()`. In the `go` function, I don't understand the purpose declaration of `lck` since it is not used. I tried removing and running and it seems fine. Is it really necessary or am I missing something?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable maybe this is clearer. "lck is not used" - but just constructing it has a very important side-effect: it locks mtx.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I need to re-check my study materials again. If I remember, the lock_guard will auto-lock the mtx. But on unique_lock, the lock method needs to be manually called to lock the mtx. Even on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock it says it doesnt lock the mutex on construction.

Comment: @newbieprogrammerz Look at overload 3, which is the one you are using, it does lock the mutex.

Comment: thanks for the info. I verified and yes overload 3 will lock the mutex. mtx.try_lock will return false after a unique lock declaration. Thanks for the clarification Nathan and Mat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
```

you create an object named `lck` that call `lock` on `mtx`.  You need this because `ready` is a non-atomic variable and writing to it without synchronization is undefined behavior since you have another thread that is reading from it.  Once `go` ends `lck` is destroyed and it automatically calls `unlock` for you.

Lock guards normally aren't "used".  We use them so that we can lock a mutex without having to worry about unlocking the mutex in every possible exit path.  To make life easy we put that unlocking code into the destructor of an object that will be destroyed on any exit path from the function so that the mutex will always be unlocked.

Comment: thanks for the useful explanation. it seems it is preferable to use unique_lock than lock_guards.  anyway this may be out of topic but just for my enrichment, is there a way to make the variables atomic without using locks. perhaps using volatile modifier? thanks for answering my question

Comment: @newbieprogrammerz You can use [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)

Comment: I will look into that. thank you so much. have a great day!

Comment: @newbieprogrammerz No problem, glad to help.  Have a nice one yourself.

Comment: @newbieprogrammerz can't use std::atomic because they are using a condition variable

Comment: @Cubbi thanks for the heads up. then I will just stick with the unique lock on this particular scenario. I will just study std::atomic and see where I can apply them in the future. :)

Comment: @Cubbi, could you provide a link?

Comment: @Surt cppreference page on condition variables mentions that